# How to install ubuntu via usb in portable drive

Tags: installation

My harddisk has been corrupted and there is no way to fix it.i am using portable drive.I want to install ubuntu in portable drive.

recently i have remove my internal hd of laptop and connect the portable one by usb.ok i also have installed ubuntu once in my portable drive.but the problem is that the boot startup hangs black/purple screen appears and it went hanging.

some people tell me its the graphic cards issue.plzz tell me how to fix this problem.  i am using dell inspiron n5010 4gbram ati hd 5650m and no internal hard drive in it only portable plugged and want to install the ubuntu in portable so i can't boot from it easily without any problems...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to take a look at this question and try out the suggestions there first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

[Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Please have a glance at the section titled, "Installing Ubuntu directly on a USB flash drive".

A quick suggestions from my side would be to try creating a Live USB from Ubuntu CD ([UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net), may help); boot from the Live USB and cross check if things look good i.e. do you still see the black/purple screen?

Comment: I have successfully insatlled ubuntu in portable with the help of unetbootin but the purple screen hangs is appearing again.The same problem occurs again.tell me how to fix this Purple boot startup hang screen problem